# Transparention of UIController in Swift - what segue chose?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to chose right segue to have good "DropDown" in swift UIKit.
Only progress I have made is this:

[image: Present modally, full screen]

or this:

[image: Present as popover]

My point is that i want the combination of these two. I don't want popover but also i wanna see the top part of the last controller. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't hand you one of these "half covering" presentations on a silver platter; you have to build it yourself. Use a presented view controller whose modal presentation style is `custom` and provide a transitioning delegate. Now you can make a custom transition animation with a custom UIPresentationController that puts *you* in charge of where the presented view controller's view will go. Adding the "shadow view" behind the presented view is up to you as well, so if you don't want it, don't add it.

Comment: Thank you, you were right that apple doesn't have it. But CocoaPods have DropDown module that works exactly I need.

Comment: Yeah, he who lives by the third-party code dies by the third-party code, but I do appreciate that sometimes you just need to get work done and move on.